# How do I get users.cache from all of the shards and put them into a collection just like the collection client.user.cache returns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js, bots

I had a discord bot which used:

```js
client.users.cache
```

This returns a Collection[Map] with all the users cached by the bot.
I added sharding and I want to do the same so I replaced it with:

```js
client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache');
```

but this returns a array and I need a Collection[Map] that is the same as the one returned from:

```js
client.users.cache
```

Does anyone know how to convert that array in a Collection[Map] the same as the one returned from:

```js
client.users.cache
```

or how to get a Collection[Map] from all the shards that looks the same as the one returned from:

```js
client.users.cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could create a new [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), iterate over the array, and insert/set new elements by using the [`set()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=set) method. Just make sure the key is the user ID, and the data is the user object:

```js
let results = await client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache');
let collection = new Discord.Collection();

results.forEach((users) => {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    collection.set(user.id, new Discord.User(client, user));
  });
});

console.log(collection);
```

`Collection` is pretty similar to [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), so there is a chance that it's also can be constructed with an iterable of two-element arrays where the first element is the key and the second is the value:

```js
let results = await client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache');
let collection = new Discord.Collection();

results.forEach((users) => {
  let userCollection = new Discord.Collection(users.map((user) => [user.id, new Discord.User(client, user)]));
  collection = collection.concat(userCollection);
});

console.log(collection);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answear, but i use it to do a forEach on all the users and the code you hav provided dosen't really work because the collection dosnet have each user marked as user so i cant do forEach user in the collection, maybe you can update the code to do that(i haven't worked much in my life with collections and maps)

Comment: I've just updated it, absolutely forgot that you received an array of arrays from `fetchClientValues`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, but the code still dosnet work for.
My code gets all the users and filters them depending on their id from files and from other stuff if they are a bot and much more and  if they pass all the if statements they get a dm and with this code is just says user.send is not a function.

Can you maybe help me fix this as well(i havent worked with sharding and collections before)

Comment: You can change `users.map((user) => [user.id, user])` to `users.map((user) => [user.id, new Discord.User(client, user)])`. I've just updated my code above. (maybe you can also use `broadcastEval` for this but I'm not so sure about that :))